# GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection using Hibernate on 11g deploying on Websphere

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, oracle11g

`org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException`: Cannot open connection

I am getting this error while performance testing. First 574 connections were established , later then I was getting this error.

I think this is a connection pooling issue?

How can this be resolved from a developer's perspective?

Comment: why do you feel that infrastructural concerns like connection pool sizes should be handled by the developer/code?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use websphere connection pool and get connection via JNDI ? If yes, admin may increase the size of connection pool from websphere console.

However I do raise a concern to check your application code for closing the connection (which ultimately goes back to connection pool), because at any point of time more than 500 open connections would seriously hamper the performance of system.

Comment: This was issue from developers perspective as I thought. Nothing to do with websphere config. A DB operation from a servlet was not included in the application context of the framework. Hence the issue, it fixed  now.